# Combination question, choosing from subgroups without replacement

Tags: combinations

I have 8 groups, each each group has 3 distinct elements, must select 1 element from each group.

How many unique arrangements can I make, selecting 1 element (of 3 choices) from 8 groups?

Is it simply $n=8 r=3$ therefore $\frac{8!}{5!3!} = 56$ .

Thanks for the help folks!

Answer (score 0):

Hint:  Is there any overlap between the groups?  If not, each choice has three options.  If so, you need to specify.